# How to use solenoid valve with vacuum pump

Tags: solenoid, solenoid-valve

I am a software developer working on small pick and place machine. I have bought mini vacuum pump and one solenoid valve. I want to control vacuum pump suction through solenoid so that when from Arduino I turn ON and OFF solenoid I can control vacuum and this way I will be able to pick and place component. But am not sure how to connect vacuum pump with solenoid  so can any one guide me on it, how to connect them.

My solenoid pic operated by 24 V.

[image]

Vacuum pump pic operated by 12 V.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Not an electrical question, maybe move to "engineering"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that solenoid valve on a vacuum system.

[image]

*Figure 1. Details printed on the valve body.*

1. It requires at least 0.15 MPa to operate. Vacuum will be negative.
2. It is pilot operated. The internal spool is moved by compressed air. You'll have rarified air.
3. The solenoid opens the pilot to allow air to move the spool.
4. It's spring return.
5. It has air assist on the return.

You need a direct acting 3/2 (3-port, 2-way) direct solenoid valve.

Comment: thanks for the info , i will buy 3 port 2 way solenoid

Comment: How does it compare with my point 1? There is no datasheet available so I wouldn't buy it anyway. Product recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Please read the entire answer as well, @Transistor said "direct acting".